# Prevent Shipping from being discounted

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, discounts

Is it possible to prevent a coupon code from also discounting the shipping costs associated with an order? We've run into a situation where a customer cart totaled $0 after they used a coupon code we configured to only work on a specific type of product which also had a separate discount available to it.

The minimum order total was met because this calculates before other discounts (in this case, it's a volume based discount).

Example:

```
Item: $25 ea
QTY: 75 

Subtotal: $1650
Volume Discount: 15% off over 20
New Total: 1,402
Shipping: 85
Special code for customer: -$1500
Order total: $0
```

What we hoped here was the order total would come to $0 + $85 shipping but I am not seeing any way to do this with discount configurations. I'm hoping I am just missing something or there is some snippet I can add somewhere to prevent this from calculating this way in the cart.